# Resizing a Container from a ActionListerner

Tags: java, swing, containers

Im not sure if this is possible but what im trying to do is resize the container on the fly. So when the user clicks login, the container will resize to display the new buttons and panels.

at the moment my code looks something like this

Container code

```
        c = getContentPane();
    c.add(panel); //panel contains login panel, user panel and system panel
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(400, 200); //width, height
    setLocation(600,0);
    setResizable(false);
    validate();
```

ActionListener

```
        loginButton.setText("Login");
    loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            c.setSize(400,630);
            c.validate();
            userScrollPane.setVisible(true);
            sysScrollPane.setVisible(true);
            resultsButtonPanel.setVisible(true);
            loginButton.setEnabled(false);
            resetButton.setEnabled(true);
            resultsButton.setEnabled(true);
            tfUser.setEditable(false);
            tfPass.setEditable(false);
            mb.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try removing `c.validate()` and adding `c.invalidate()` at the end.

Comment: @DavidConrad cheers man, didnt work though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setPreferedSize and then pack in your Actionlistener to resize the panel on the fly

Answer (score 0):

> //panel contains login panel, user panel and system panel

A panel should only be used for one purpose. If you have multiple functions then create multiple panels.

Then you can use a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to swap the panels in the GUI as required.

Comment: I dont need to swap out the panels. upon successful login all panels should be visible to the user. @camickr